# Uploading app on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to python and google app. I have an already created application in python and 
 google app engine. I have downloaded source code of the app and customized it. The  source 
 code which i downloaded doesn't have app.yaml and index.yaml in it. Now i want to know that  if i upload my app on google app engine without app.yaml and index.yaml then is there any chance that my data on live server get lost. Please show me right path i am doing any
 thing wrong. Also i dont know how to upload a single file on google app engine. Should i have to upload whole app ?
i have used following command for downloading source code on localhost:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot upload an application without an app.yaml. The app.yaml file contains the necessary configurations to run your application like handlers to use, application ID, runtime, and so on.

Also, you cannot upload a single file to App Engine, you always upload the entire app.

I strongly suggest you do the "Getting Started" guide:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/
before you invest more time in trying to figure out why things don't work.